# Как не отображать пустые строки, используя print_r для вывода массива на экран?

Tags: php, массивы

Использую конструкцию `<pre><?= print_r($a, true) ?></pre>` чтобы отобразить массив monospace-шрифтом и сделать отображение как можно более компактным. К сожалению, никак не удаётся удалить все пустые строки, как на изображении ниже:

[image: как удалить пустую строку?]

Пробовал `array_filter($a, 'strlen')` но в PHP 8 такой вызов `strlen` выдаёт предупреждение. Затем пробовал вот такой callback:

```
print_r(
  array_filter($a, function($x) { return !( ($x === '\r\n') or ($x === '') ); }), true
);
```

но этот вариант тоже не проходит.
Может быть есть какая-то специфика `print_r()` о которой я не подозреваю?

Comment: А смысл всего этого в чем?

Comment: @u_mulder, изначально написал в чём смысл.

Comment: `\n\n`  замените